# MYSQL 5.7.20 - Left join with order by a coalesced column - very strange behavior

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, coalesce, mysql-5.7

I'm facing a very strange issue that I hope you can explain to me.
What I'm trying to do is order a resultset based on a coalesced column in a subquery. Let me explain better.

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `user_favorites_user` (
  `source_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `favorited_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `source_user_id` (`source_user_id`),
  KEY `favorited_user_id` (`favorited_user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_favorites_user_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`source_user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_favorites_user_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`favorited_user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

As one user (let's say ID=1) is browsing the website, I would like to show him other users ordered with his favorites at the bottom.
So, I start with this query:

```
select user.*, coalesce(favorites.is_favorited,0) as is_favorited_coalesced from user
left join (
select 1 as is_favorited, favorited_user_id from user_favorites_user
where source_user_id = '1'
) favorites on favorites.favorited_user_id = user.id
```

So far so good, this is what I get and I expected:

```
+----+-------+------------------------+
| id | name  | is_favorited_coalesced |
+----+-------+------------------------+
|  3 | user3 |                      1 |
|  4 | user4 |                      1 |
|  1 | user1 |                      0 |
|  2 | user2 |                      0 |
+----+-------+------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, I want to order the resultset. I thought that an ORDER BY clause may suffice:

```
select user.*, coalesce(favorites.is_favorited,0) as is_favorited_coalesced from user
left join (
select 1 as is_favorited, favorited_user_id from user_favorites_user
where source_user_id = '1'
) favorites on favorites.favorited_user_id = user.id
order by is_favorited_coalesced asc
```

At this point, I get the same result as above:

```
+----+-------+------------------------+
| id | name  | is_favorited_coalesced |
+----+-------+------------------------+
|  3 | user3 |                      1 |
|  4 | user4 |                      1 |
|  1 | user1 |                      0 |
|  2 | user2 |                      0 |
+----+-------+------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I then thought the coalesce is not good for sorting on-the-fly, so I added a wrapper query but the result is still the same.

Why the ORDER BY is_favorited_coalesced is not working? What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**
I tried using:

```
order by coalesce(favorites.is_favorited,0) asc
```

instead of the alias but I got the same results:

```
    select user.*, coalesce(favorites.is_favorited,0) as is_favorited_coalesced from user left join ( select 1 as is_favorited, favorited_user_id from user_favorites_user where source_user_id = '1' ) favorites on favorites.favorited_user_id = user.id order by coalesce(favorites.is_favorited,0)
--------------

+----+-------+------------------------+
| id | name  | is_favorited_coalesced |
+----+-------+------------------------+
|  3 | user3 |                      1 |
|  4 | user4 |                      1 |
|  1 | user1 |                      0 |
|  2 | user2 |                      0 |
+----+-------+------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT 2**
I've found another strange behavior. If I try to order by the ID column, this is what I get:

```
--------------
select user.*, coalesce(favorites.is_favorited,0) as is_favorited_coalesced from user left join ( select 1 as is_favorited, favorited_user_id from user_favorites_user where source_user_id = '1' ) favorites on favorites.favorited_user_id = user.id order by id asc
--------------

+----+-------+------------------------+
| id | name  | is_favorited_coalesced |
+----+-------+------------------------+
|  1 | user1 |                      1 |
|  2 | user2 |                      1 |
|  3 | user3 |                      1 |
|  4 | user4 |                      1 |
+----+-------+------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have no clue why this is happening.
I'm using MySQL 5.7.20 on a virtualized Fedora 25 under windows using VirtualBox.

**EDIT 3**

As suggested in the comments I've run:

```
mysql> explain select user.*, coalesce(favorites.is_favorited,0) as is_favorited_coalesced from user left join ( select 1 as is_favorited, favorited_user_id from user_favorites_user where source_user_id = '1' ) favorites on favorites.favorited_user_id = user.id order by is_favorited_coalesced asc;show warnings;
+----+-------------+---------------------+------------+-------+----------------------------------+----------------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table               | partitions | type  | possible_keys                    | key            | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------------+-------+----------------------------------+----------------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user                | NULL       | ALL   | NULL                             | NULL           | NULL    | NULL |    4 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user_favorites_user | NULL       | range | source_user_id,favorited_user_id | source_user_id | 4       | NULL |    2 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------------+-------+----------------------------------+----------------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select `so_test`.`user`.`id` AS `id`,`so_test`.`user`.`name` AS `name`,coalesce(1,0) AS `is_favorited_coalesced` from `so_test`.`user` left join (`so_test`.`user_favorites_user`) on(((`so_test`.`user_favorites_user`.`favorited_user_id` = `so_test`.`user`.`id`) and (`so_test`.`user_favorites_user`.`source_user_id` = '1'))) where 1 order by `is_favorited_coalesced` |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Also:

```
mysql> SELECT @@sql_mode;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                                                                                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT 4:**

I've run:

```
mysql> SELECT @@optimizer_switch;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@optimizer_switch                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=on |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As stated in the comments.

---

Including the dataset for fast testing:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET time_zone = '+00:00';
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'user1'),
(2, 'user2'),
(3, 'user3'),
(4, 'user4');

CREATE TABLE `user_favorites_user` (
  `source_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `favorited_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `source_user_id` (`source_user_id`),
  KEY `favorited_user_id` (`favorited_user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_favorites_user_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`source_user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_favorites_user_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`favorited_user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `user_favorites_user` (`source_user_id`, `favorited_user_id`) VALUES
(1, 3),
(1, 4);
```

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1660d5/1

Comment: @juergend It works on the sqlfiddle, so I have no clue why it is not working on my machine. I also found another strange behavior, I'll update my question now. Thank you

Comment: Can you execute a `explain <query>; show warnings;` like this ( https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nyRL2hGSUSs8XqwPQ8UARx/4 ) and post the results here this way we can how the MySQL optimizer is rewritting or handling the query.. You also see the optimizer is optimizing `coalesce(favorites.is_favorited,0)` with `coalesce(1,0) AS `is_favorited_coalesced`

Comment: Also can also post the SQL_modes off the MySQL server. `SELECT @@sql_mode`

Comment: @RaymondNijland Done, I've updated the question

Comment: I tryed running the example with your sql_mode ( https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nyRL2hGSUSs8XqwPQ8UARx/15 ) still can't reproduce the problem so it might be a other optimizer setting ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/switchable-optimizations.html ) otherwise iam out off ideas.. Can you post the output off `SELECT @@optimizer_switch;`

Comment: @RaymondNijland Done and updated the question with edit#4

Comment: I can reproduce on Rextester which is running 5.7.12. This is a BUG IMO. [Playground here](http://rextester.com/live/DNSZJ93513)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the bug [Query returns wrong data if order by is present](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90847) (or at least closely related).

It is (in a very similar form) still present in MySQL 8.0.12 (see e.g. [your example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0aff491f1dd2e0786622aa365cd25e98) in dbfiddle, although it will hopefully not show the incorrect behaviour once it is fixed): while it actually orders correctly now (probably because you do a calculation on it), it still returns the incorrect value for `is_favorited`:

```
select user.*, favorites.is_favorited, 
coalesce(favorites.is_favorited,0) as is_favorited_coalesced from user
left join (
select 1 as is_favorited, favorited_user_id from user_favorites_user
where source_user_id = '1'
) favorites on favorites.favorited_user_id = user.id
order by is_favorited_coalesced desc

+----+-------+--------------+------------------------+
| id | name  | is_favorited | is_favorited_coalesced |
+----+-------+--------------+------------------------+
|  1 | user1 |              |                      1 |
|  2 | user2 |              |                      1 |
|  3 | user3 |              |                      0 |
|  4 | user4 |              |                      0 |
+----+-------+--------------+------------------------+
```

It seems to be an optimizer problem related to (non-)materialization (MySQL 5.7 had a lot of those). You can workaround most of those bugs by forcing materialization of the derived table (e.g. by adding a `limit`):

```
select user.*, favorites.is_favorited, 
coalesce(favorites.is_favorited,0) as is_favorited_coalesced from user
left join (
select 1 as is_favorited, favorited_user_id from user_favorites_user
where source_user_id = '1' limit 1000000
) favorites on favorites.favorited_user_id = user.id
order by is_favorited_coalesced desc

+----+-------+--------------+------------------------+
| id | name  | is_favorited | is_favorited_coalesced |
+----+-------+--------------+------------------------+
|  1 | user1 |            1 |                      1 |
|  2 | user2 |            1 |                      1 |
|  3 | user3 |              |                      0 |
|  4 | user4 |              |                      0 |
+----+-------+--------------+------------------------+
```

As @RaymondNijland mentioned, there are other workarounds, e.g. disabling Derived Table Merging with [`set [GLOBAL|SESSION] optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off'`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/switchable-optimizations.html) before you run that query. You could also use this to disable the feature globally until the bug gets fixed, so you do not have to inspect every query if it's broken, and just enable it for queries you have verfied that they are not affected (so they can profit from that optimization again).

Comment: Thank you, I would have smashed my head for ages on this. Marking as accepted.

Comment: @ruddle i had a feeling this was the problem whats why i asked for the optimizer_switch config.  Only problem is that `LIMIT 1000000` will always trigger `Using temporary; Using filesort` which is far from optimal  better is to use `SET SESSION optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off';` see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hHLRPtL9K65Ag2xEhNaicL/5 .

Comment: @RaymondNijland While there are several methods to workaround this, both the switch and `limit` should behave exactly the same (and I think they shouldn't provoke more filesorts than `limit`, without `order by` inside the derived table of course). The advantage of using `limit` is that it can be used surgically where needed (not every derived table, maybe not even inside the same query requires a fix) and doesn't need a 2nd query, while the switch could be used globally without the need to check every query if it's broken. I'll add that option to the answer.

Comment: "While there are several methods to workaround this, both the switch and limit should behave exactly the sam" In this case it seams to be a yes.. Because the query orders on a aliased column (which will use a "Using filesort" for sure "Using temporary" can also come in when the optimizer thinks it needs to sort a large number of records) better is to check both workarounds with `EXPLAIN` to make sure which workaround generates the best query plan..

Comment: "I think they shouldn't provoke more filesorts than limit, without order by inside the derived table of course" Iam more worried about the combination "Using filesort; Using temporary" which can become alot off random disk I/O when the temporary table is written to disk.. And a `LIMIT` with a large number always seams to always use "Using filesort; Using temporary" in the explain...

Comment: @RaymondNijland I might be missing a point (and maybe some special cases), but `limit` imho doesn't automatically imply a filesort - although it of course usually implies an `order by` to make sense, which in turn can require a filesort; but here, it's a `limit` without `order by`! It should behave like disabled merging (although checking the explain plan to verify that is never a bad idea), and both will require a temporary table (which will not necessarily be on disk, even with limit `1000000000`), which is the main idea of both workarounds.

Comment: True LIMIT with ORDER BY on a non-indexed or aliased column will **always** need a "Using filesort; Using temporary"  i explained it unclear in mine last comment i notice now.."and both will require a temporary table (which will not necessarily be on disk, even with limit 1000000000)" No indeed i did say "which can become alot off random disk I/O **when** the temporary table is written to disk" it depens  on a server config or used queries/table column datatypes described here here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html